# How to remove the Close Tabs in Caliburn Micro MVVM application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabs, caliburn.micro

I have built an application in MVVM using Caliburn Micro. I currently have the closetab working on all my tabs, and it closes all tabs apart from the first three, which are Home, Payment, Notes however, I would like it to NOT show the close tab icon on the first three tabs as shown in my AppViewModel code:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Items" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!-- The Tab Names Binding with DisplayName-->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                    <!-- The Tab Close Icon-->
                    <Button Content="x" x:Name="CloseTab" cal:Message.Attach="CloseTab" Style="{DynamicResource appTabCloseButton}" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

My AppViewModel code behind for the close tab:

```
public void CloseTab()
{
    if(ActiveItem.DisplayName == "Home" || ActiveItem.DisplayName == "Payment" || ActiveItem.DisplayName == "Notes")
    {
      MessageBox.Show("This Tab Cannot Be closed.","Permanent Tab");

    } else {
        DeactivateItem(ActiveItem, close: true);
    }  
}
```

My App.xaml code for the boolToVis:

```
<Application x:Class="WPF.Test.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF.Test.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:Bootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
                    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVis" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Global.WPF.UserControls;component/Resources/brushes.xaml" />
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Global.WPF.UserControls;component/Resources/CommonControls.xaml" />
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Global.WPF.UserControls;component/Resources/menuItems.xaml" />
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
                    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and finally the visibility for the binding:

```
bool _visibility;
public bool Visibility
{
    get { return _visibility; }
    set
    {
        _visibility = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("Visibility");
    }
}
```

I would be happy for any suggestions as I'm totally lost!!

Comment: Wrap the button in a guard panel. create a `bool CanClose` property if one does not already exist. panels bound to boolean properties automatically hide when value is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Guard Panel that can be used to show/hide the button.

```
<TabControl x:Name="Items" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!-- The Tab Names Binding with DisplayName-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                <Border x:Name="CanCloseTab">
                    <!-- The Tab Close Icon-->
                    <Button Content="x" x:Name="CloseTab" cal:Message.Attach="CloseTab" Style="{DynamicResource appTabCloseButton}" />
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Then create a guard property

```
public bool CanCloseTab {
    get { 
        return !(ActiveItem.DisplayName == "Home" 
                 || ActiveItem.DisplayName == "Payment" 
                 || ActiveItem.DisplayName == "Notes");
    }
}
```

By convention the view should automatically bind the `CanCloseTab` property to the visibility of the panel (Border) so that when false it will not display. If the panel was not there the guard property would have also automatically disabled the button.

This should now allow the CloseTab method to be refactored for simplicity.

```
public void CloseTab() {
    if(CanCloseTab) {
        DeactivateItem(ActiveItem, close: true);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this help. It no longer displays the X icon on the tabs however it leaves a circle. It was previously a tab with a circle and an X in it. I'm think this is the style dynamic resource that needs to be hidden?

Comment: @JasonB May be a style yes. The code you showed has no indication of what component could be the cause of the circle.

Comment: I'll work on it for now. Certainly further on from where I was so I've marked your answer. The styles are in globals so I can't touch them so think I need to just look at the visibility.